# why Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I met a weird circumstance. I wanted to make two LikedList. I know there many ways to do this, however, in the following code, alist can perfectly show but blist failed.
and it shows "Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NullPointerException`". Could anyone explain to me why? thanks.

```
public static void InNum(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        int k= input.nextInt();
            alist.add(k);
            }
    System.out.println("the alist is="+alist);
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++){
        int m= input.nextInt();
            blist.add(m);
            }
        }
```

Comment: where is `alist` and `blist` defined and initialized

Comment: oops, I defined it in a wrong way... public static LinkedList<Integer> blist;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to intialize alist and blist. Refer the following code:

```
public static void inNum() {
    List<Integer> alist= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> blist= new ArrayList<Integer>();

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            int k= input.nextInt();
                alist.add(k);
        }

        System.out.println("the alist is="+alist);
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++){
            int m= input.nextInt();
                blist.add(m);
        }


}
```